# Subspace clustering in R using package orclus

Tags: r, clustering

Currently I am working on some subspace clustering issues. I found one useful package in R called [orclus](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/orclus/versions/0.2-6/topics/orclus), which implemented one subspace clustering algorithm called orclus.

As stated in the package description, there are two key parameters to be determined. One is the subspace dimensionality and the other one is the cluster number. It is stated that to determine the optimal value of subspace dimensionality, one statistic, the cluster sparsity coefficient can be used. The closer the statistic to zero, the better the performance. However, when actually trying this implementation, I found that the statistic is minimal when subspace dimensionality is 1; and the larger the subspace dimensionality, the larger the statistic. Does it make sense? I was not expecting such monotonic trend.

Answer (score 5):

ORCLUS is really really limited in usefulness. I have yet to see someone report good results in practise. In essence, it is Proclus reiterated with PCA, if I recall correctly. And proclus also had similar issues in all of my experiments!

If you want to try out some more advanced methods, have a look at [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/) which includes a number of subspace and correlation clustering algorithms. Including ORCLUS, so maybe this implementation works better for you?

Comment: Thanks for pointing to ELKI. In your knowledge, is there any other package in `R` which implements subspace clustering. While searching, I found `orclus` and `subspace`. I think both of them do not include all the  clustering methods.

Comment: I don't use R much. CRAN is huge, but the quality of packages varies. Some packages are amazing, others unbearably slow, and unmaintained. In many cases, suthors just dump a prototype and forget it, unfortunately. But worst of all, they tend to be largely incompatible, so you end up wrting the same code again for every CRAN package you use. :-(